# Basic auth Spring resttemplate examples and they all use an Account.class. What is it?

Tags: rest, maven, spring-mvc, resttemplate

Here's a typical example of what I find:

```
 HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
 ResponseEntity<Account> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,
     HttpMethod.GET, request, Account.class);
 Account account = response.getBody();
```

I've googled looking for any reference to the Account.class.  So far I've come up empty.  I can't find it in Spring 4 JavaDocs. Can anyone tell me where it's documented and is there a Maven dependency that includes the necesssry jars?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Acoount.class is not a part of any jar. It's a class in your application.
It is used by rest template to map the response to an object. Here is what I mean:
if the response is:

```
{"name": name, "balance": 1000}
```

And you have:

```
class Account {
    private String name;
    private int balance;

    // setters/getters
}
```

Then the code you provided will return you an instance of the Account.

That's it!